# Is there a way I could receive a SUM of each column and AVG balance amount SERIOUSLY STUMPED

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT golf_card_id, AVG(balance_amount), SUM(balance_amount) 
FROM
(SELECT gc.golf_card_id, gc.claims_id, o.id AS order_id, gc.merchandise_id, b.id as Balls_ID, o.balance_amount
FROM m_golf_card_value_additions as gc
JOIN m_orders AS o ON gc.order_id=o.id
JOIN m_bundles as b on o.bundle_id=b.id
where gc.merchandies_id = '392476' AND complaint = 'disputed_successfully'
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6) GCV
GROUP BY 1`
```

I am attempting to receive the sum of each column and also the average of balance amount. Can anyone help?? Been stuck for hours trying to find the correct query to answer a question

Comment: What's wrong with what you wrote? Show  sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Showing some example data, including the result from your current query and the expected result would help us to decipher your actual intent here

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT gc.golf_card_id, AVG(o.balance_amount), SUM(o.balance_amount) 
FROM m_golf_card_value_additions as gc
JOIN m_orders AS o ON gc.order_id=o.id
JOIN m_bundles as b on o.bundle_id=b.id
where gc.merchandies_id = '392476' AND complaint = 'disputed_successfully'
GROUP BY gc.golf_card_id
```

This should give you the average and total balance amount per golf card, if that is what you are after. Your use of the `GROUP BY` column doesn't make much sense to me, so its hard to figure out what you are trying to do there.